# Dot Net: Not letting user to access web without inserting credentials, even if they change URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, redirect

I have a system in which it is necessary for users to pass through login section to access home page. I am able to do that using asp C# Ado and SQL. But the problem is security. Still users are able to access Home Page without entering credentials by simply changing the URL. When users will open the website the URL will be this:

> www.domain.co/Login.aspx

If any user changes it to this:

> www.domain.co/Home.aspx

Still they will be able to access it. I do not want it. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Are you using Web Forms? Asp.Net MVC?

Comment: Web Forms @hernanat

Answer (score 0):

Hope that you know the use and advantages of `session`. You can make use of it.

What you want to do is:

1. Create a session variable(let it be `user_id`) set its value as the id of the current user if the user successfully logged into the site. Which means session["user_id"] having the user id if there is any logged user.
2. You can check for `session["user_id"]` in the load event of other pages, if it is `null` means throw him out( redirect to the login page).

**Creating session:**

```
session["user_id"] = "Id of the user"; // This will be the unique identifier
```

This will be added after checking his/her credentials and are valid.

**Checking session in the Home page/ or any other page:**

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(session["user_id"]))
   Response.Redirect("Login.Aspx");
```

Comment: Yes I know how to use sessions well. Is it secure?

Comment: I tried it. It is showing this message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: have you assign the value to the session before checking? try this `if(session["user_id"]!= null && session["user_id"].ToString()!="")`

Comment: Basically, I am reading user Id from dataTable and initializing it to session["user_id"] and redirecting to Home Page. There I am checking if its null or not.

Comment: This article describes the issue : [Read this](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_)

Answer (score 0):

If your are not using it already, you should see how to add Forms Authentication: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301240

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO" loginUrl="logon.aspx" 
   protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

Then you can deny access to anonymous users to all the site doing:

```
<authorization>
   <deny users ="?" />
   <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

Or to specific pages:

```
<location path="Restricted.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users ="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: in config I added authorization. Now it is not taking to home page even if user name and password are correct?